# Google Play store on emulator in Android studio in Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, google-play

I have installed android studio in windows and want to install Google play store on the emulator. I read this [guide](http://www.flinkd.org/2015/02/installing-google-play-on-the-android-emulator-api-21-lollipop/), but I don't know where unzip the file `gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip`.
The file was downloaded to the user's download folder.
The path of the sdk folder is: **C:\Android\sdk**

Comment: unzip the files anywhere and just drag & drop .apk files on the emulator window.

Comment: Which is the emulator window, C:\Android\sdk\tools?